# how to invoke a method on a value change of a variable?

Tags: c#, listener, invoke

I want invoke `VoiceSearch()` method when a value of my `keyword`(string variable) change.

```
private void VoiceSearch()
    {
        try
        {
            query.Append(keyword);

            Browser.Navigate(query.ToString());

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

**solution**

```
private string _keyword
public string keyword
{
  get
  { 
    return _keyword;
  }
  set
  {
    _keyword=value;
    VoiceSearch();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simplest way to do this is implement `keyword` as a property:

```
private string _keyword
public string keyword
{
  get
  { 
    return _keyword;
  }
  set
  {
    _keyword=value;
    VoiceSearch();
  }
}
```

Here, `_keyword` is what is referred to as a "backing variable". There are interfaces such as `INotifyPropertyChanged` which are very commonly used in databinding that are worth looking into, but in your case, the minimum code you have to write is this example.

Answer (score 2):

Either declare `keyword` as a property and invoke `VoiceSearch` in the setter or create a special method for setting the `keyword` and invoke `VoiceSearch` from it when called.

**Property**

```
private string keyword;
public string Keyword
{
    get { return keyword; }
    set { keyword = value; VoiceSearch(); }
}
```

**Method**

```
public void SetKeyword(string value)
{
    keyword = value;
    VoiceSearch();
}
```

Assuming that `keyword` is actually `string`. These two options still leaves you with a chance to change the variable and not call `VoiceSearch()`.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into INotifyPropertyChanged. Instead of variable I would suggest to use property. See a MSDN example below:

```
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace SDKSample
{
  // This class implements INotifyPropertyChanged 
  // to support one-way and two-way bindings 
  // (such that the UI element updates when the source 
  // has been changed dynamically) 
  public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
      private string name;
      // Declare the event 
      public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

      public Person()
      {
      }

      public Person(string value)
      {
          this.name = value;
      }

      public string PersonName
      {
          get { return name; }
          set
          {
              name = value;
              // Call OnPropertyChanged whenever the property is updated
              OnPropertyChanged("PersonName");
          }
      }

      // Create the OnPropertyChanged method to raise the event 
      protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
      {
          PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
          if (handler != null)
          {
              handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
          }
      }
  }
}
```